# Is there are a fast (O(1)) way to find the position of the set bit in a one-hot binary sequence?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

Given a binary number/sequence, find the positions/bit indices of the 1/ON/SET/HIGH bits. As an example, given the binary number:

```
  76543210 # positions
0b10010110 # binary number
  ^  ^ ^^
```

the positions would be `[1,2,4,7]`.

I have the following O(N) algorithm (where N is the bit length of the binary number):

```
def get_on_positions(num):
    res = []
    pos = 0
    while num:
        if num & 0b1:
            res.append(pos)
        num >>= 1
        pos += 1
    return res

assert(get_on_positions(0b10010110) == [1,2,4,7])
```

But I was wondering: is there was a faster O(M) algorithm (where M is the count of ON/SET/HIGH bits in the binary number). A particular case where the difference between N (the bit length) and M (the count of ON/SET/HIGH bits) can be significant is when the binary number is one-hot. A one-hot binary number has exactly one of its bits ON/SET/HIGH). For example `0b10000000` (or any power of 2). In the one-hot case, is there an O(1) algorithm for finding the position of the single ON/SET/HIGH bit? As a side note, the case where `num` is one-hot case is equivalent to finding `log_2(num)`.